# IBM Domino custom login form load issue

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, login-page

I created domcfg db on my server, made a copy of $$LoginUserForm, customize it and set proper mapping. After all those operations i am able to modify my form as i wish, but ...

All the content, which is located below the login form (i didn't change it - only modify css) - doesn't render. Here is image:

[image]

All html code, which is located above table - is loaded, but below the table - whatever i'm adding - nothing is loading below the login form. What can be wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Sign In button closes the form. So comment out the Sign In button. You then need to add your own button and can then add more content below it.

Here's an example of a OneUI login form:

[image]

Comment: Ah, okay. Now it is clear. But how can i move submit button below the form, if the form is generated automatically while load? Or should i use HTML type of content for this form?

Comment: The simpe solution is to comment out the Sign In button and then add your own button. I will update my answer with a more simple example

Comment: I understood your point. But domino generates in form all the content ( [link]http://i.imgur.com/RhiIOGR.png ) . So, when i move standard button below my content and create my own button ( [link]http://i.imgur.com/gEzPHXo.png ) - result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Moving submit below the form doesn't help, so i used dirty trick. Maybe for someone it will be helpful.

1. add jquery to header
2. add custom script like:

   var content = "%your content%"
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $( "form" ).append(content)
     });